# Lightweight implementation of the in-close algorithm from C++ to C# translation

Tags: c#, c++, algorithm, object-oriented

The following C++ code is a lightweight implementation of in-close algorithm. Full details of the project can be found [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/inclose/files/In-Close2/).

I was trying to translate the C++ code to C# but it's very difficult to manage. That new version simply doesn't work due to pointer implementation. In fact, I need to keep using pointers because performance is very important to me.

The actual code I need to use in C++ version:

```
#include <fstream>          //for file IO
#include <iostream>         //for cin >> and cout <<
#include <conio.h>          //for _kbhit
#include <string.h>         //for strings
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

//MAX VALUES:
#define MAX_CONS 50000000   //max number of concepts
#define MAX_COLS 5000       //max number of attributes
#define MAX_ROWS 1000000        //max number of objects
#define MAX_FOR_B 50000000  //memory for storing intents
#define MAX_FOR_A 1000000000    //memory for storing extents
//Change these in the as required and available RAM allows. Current values are for standard 64 bit Windows PC with 8GB RAM

__declspec(align(32)) unsigned __int64 **contextTemp;   //temporary context matrix for input of cxt file and physical sorting of columns
__declspec(align(32)) unsigned __int64 **context;       //the context matrix used for concept mining. 

//the bit-wise columns in 'contextTemp' are transposed into bit-wise rows in 'context' for more efficient use of cache memory
int mArray;                 //size of bit-wise columns in temp context
int nArray;                 //size of bit-wise rows in context                          

int colOriginal[MAX_COLS];      //maps sorted columns to original order
int colSup[MAX_COLS];           //column support (for sorting and skipping empty columns)
int rowOriginal[MAX_ROWS];      //maps ham-sorted rows to original order

int n;      //no of attributes {0,1,...,n-1} 
int m;      //no of objects    {0,1,...,m-1} 

/************************ linked list form of B[MAX_CONS][n] ******************************************/
short int* B;                           //pointer to intents (tree in linear array) - memory allocated at start of main
short int sizeBnode[MAX_CONS];          //the no. of attributes at a node (concept labels)
short int * startB[MAX_CONS];           //pointers to start of intents
int nodeParent[MAX_CONS];               //links to parent node in tree
unsigned __int64 Bparent[MAX_COLS/64 + 1];  //parent intent in Boolean form (attributes currently involved)
short int sizeB[MAX_CONS];              //intent sizes (calculated after con gen for analysis purposes)
short int * bptr;                   //initialise B pointer to start of B

/************************ linear form of A[MAX_CONS][m] ***************************************/

int* A;                                 //pointer to extents - memory is allocated at start of main
int* startA[MAX_CONS];                  //pointers to start of extents
int sizeA[MAX_CONS];                    //extent sizes (calculated after con gen for analysis purposes)

int highc = 1;          //highest concept number
int minIn = 0;          //minimum size of intent (min support)
int minEx = 0;          //minimum size of extent (min support)
int startCol = 0;       //starting column for iteration (to skip empty cols)
int numcons = 0;        //number of concepts

int main()                  
{
    A = new int[MAX_FOR_A];
    B = new short int[MAX_FOR_B];
    bptr = B;

    void InClose   (const int c, const int y, const unsigned __int64 *Bparent); //incremental concept closure functions
    void cxtFileInput();            //input context in Burmeister format

    cxtFileInput();
    for(int i = 0; i < MAX_COLS/64 + 1; i++) Bparent[i] = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < m; i++) A[i] = i;
    startA[0] = &A[0];
    startA[1] = &A[m];
    sizeB[0] = 0;
    startB[0] = &B[0];
    nodeParent[0] = -1; //supremun does not have a parent
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) colOriginal[i] = i; //init column index array for sorting
    startCol = 0;
    while(colSup[startCol] == 0) startCol++;
    InClose(0, startCol, Bparent);
}

void InClose(const int c, const int y, const unsigned __int64 *Bparent)
{   
    bool IsCannonical(const int y,  const int * endAhighc, const unsigned __int64 Bchild[]);
    int Bchildren[MAX_COLS];                            //the attributes that will spawn new concepts
    int numchildren = 0;                                //the number of new concepts spawned from current one
    int Cnums[MAX_COLS];                                //the concept no.s of the spawned concepts
    unsigned __int64 Bchild[MAX_COLS/64 + 1];               //the current intent in Boolean form

    memcpy(Bchild,Bparent,nArray*8);    //set the child attributes to the parent ones (inheritance)

    if(c){      //if not concept 0, add the spawning attribute to intent
        Bchild[(y-1)>>6] = Bchild[(y-1)>>6] | (1i64 << ((y-1) % 64));
        *bptr = y-1;
        bptr++;
        sizeBnode[c]++;
    }
    int sizeAc = startA[c+1]-startA[c];         //calculate the size of current extent
    for(int j = y; j < n; j++) {
        if(!(Bchild[j>>6] & (1i64 << (j % 64)))){
            int * Ac = startA[c];                       //pointer to start of current extent
            int * aptr = startA[highc];                 //pointer to start of next extent to be created
            for(int i = sizeAc; i > 0; i--){
                if(context[*Ac][j>>6] & (1i64 << (j % 64))){//context[*Ac][J] where J is byte J div 8, bit J mod 8
                    *aptr = *Ac;                        //add object to new extent (intersection)
                    aptr++;
                }
                Ac++;                                   //next object
            }

            int size = aptr - startA[highc];            //calculate size of intersection

            if(size==0){
                Bchild[j>>6] = Bchild[j>>6] | (1i64 << (j % 64));   //intersection is empty, so the column can be ignored in subsequent levels
            }
            else {
                if(size < sizeAc){
                    if(IsCannonical(j,aptr,Bchild)){    //if the intersection is a new extent, note the child for later spawning:
                        Bchildren[numchildren] = j;         //note where (attribute column) it was found,
                        Cnums[numchildren++] = highc;       //note the concept number,
                        nodeParent[highc] = c;              //note the parent concept number and
                        startA[++highc] = aptr;             //note the start of the new extent in A.                
                    }
                }
                else {      //size == sizeAc: extent is unchanged
                    *bptr = j;                          //add current attribute to intent
                    bptr++;
                    Bchild[j>>6] = Bchild[j>>6] | (1i64 << (j % 64));       //record that the attribute will be inherited by any child concepts
                    sizeBnode[c]++;                     //increment the number of attributes at this node in the B tree
                }
            }
        }
    }
    for(int i = numchildren-1; i >= 0 ; i--){
        startB[Cnums[i]] = bptr;                        //set the start of the intent in B tree
        InClose(Cnums[i], Bchildren[i]+1, Bchild);      //close the child concept (next closure starts at j-1 to
    }                                                   //avoid having to create this intersection again)
}

bool IsCannonical(const int y, const int * endAhighc, const unsigned __int64 Bchild[])
{
    unsigned __int64 Bmask[MAX_COLS/64 + 1];
    int p;
    for(p = 0; p < y>>6; p++){
        Bmask[p]=~Bchild[p]; //invert 32 bit chunks of current intent
    }
    Bmask[p]= ~Bchild[p] & ((1i64 << (y % 64))-1); //invert last 32 bits up to current attribute

    for(p=0; p <= y>>6; p++){
        int i;
        int * Ahighc = startA[highc];   //find start of extent                                      
        for(i = endAhighc - Ahighc; i > 0; i--){     //iterate from number of objects downto zero
            Bmask[p] = Bmask[p] & context[*Ahighc][p]; //apply mask to context (testing 32 cells at a time)
            if(!Bmask[p])break;     //if there is nothing still true then stop looking down this 32 columns
            Ahighc++;               //otherwise, next object
        }
        if(i==0) return(false); 
    }
    return(true);   //if intersection is not found, it is cannonical
}

void cxtFileInput()     //input data from Burmeister cxt file
{
    int i,j;            //object and attribute counters
    ifstream cxtFile;
    cxtFile.open (fname);

    cout << "\n\nReading data...";
    char Bchar;                         
    cxtFile >> Bchar;   //strip out the 'B' at top of Burmeister cxt file!
    cxtFile >> m;       //input number of objects
    cxtFile >> n;       //input number of attributes

    /* create temporary context for sorting*/
    mArray = (m-1)/64 + 1;                          //calculate size of second dimension (objects) - 1bit per object
    contextTemp = new __declspec(align(32)) unsigned __int64*[n];               //create one dimension of the temporary context
    for (j = 0;j < n;j++){                          //for each attribute
        contextTemp[j] = new __declspec(align(32)) unsigned __int64[mArray];    //create a row of objects
        for(i=0;i<mArray;i++) contextTemp[j][i]=0;
    }

    /* create context */
    nArray = (n-1)/64 + 1;                      //calculate size of second dimension (attributes) - 1bit per object
    context = new __declspec(align(32)) unsigned __int64*[m];               //create one dimension of the context
    for (i = 0;i < m;i++){                      //for each object
        context[i] = new __declspec(align(32)) unsigned __int64[nArray];    //create a row of attributes
        for(j=0;j<nArray;j++) context[i][j]=0;
    }

    /* strip out blank lines in cxt file */
    char blank[512];
    cxtFile.getline(blank,512);
    cxtFile.getline(blank,512);

    /* create arrays for object and attribute names */
    onames = new char*[m];
    for (i = 0;i < m;i++) onames[i] = new char[512];
    anames = new char*[n];
    for (i = 0;i < n;i++) anames[i] = new char[512];

    /* get object and attribute names */
    for(i = 0; i < m; i++)
        cxtFile.getline(onames[i],512);
    for(j = 0; j < n; j++)
        cxtFile.getline(anames[j],512);

    /* create input row (instance) of context grid to be input from file */
    char *instance;                                 
    int instanceSize = (n+2);                       
    instance = new char[instanceSize];

    /* input instances and translate into temporary context */
    for(i = 0; i < m; i++){                             //for each row (object),
        cxtFile.getline(instance, instanceSize);        //get instance.
        for(j = 0;j < n; j++){                          //for each attribute,
            if(instance[j] == 'X'){                     //if object has the attibute,
                contextTemp[j][(i>>6)] |= (1i64<<(i%64));   //set context bit to true where I is byte: i div 8, bit: i mod 8
                colSup[j]++;                            //increment column support for attribute j
            }
        }
    }
    cxtFile.close();
}
```

And my translation to C#:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    unsafe class CMiner
    {
        Int64[][] contextTemp;
        Int64[][] context;
        const int MAX_CONS = 5000000;
        const int MAX_COLS = 5000;
        const int MAX_ROWS = 1000000;
        const int MAX_FOR_B = 5000000;
        const int MAX_FOR_A = 1000000;
        int mArray;
        int nArray;
        int[] colOriginal = new int[MAX_COLS];
        int[] colSup = new int[MAX_COLS];
        int[] rowOriginal = new int[MAX_ROWS];
        int n;
        int m;
        int* B;
        int[] Real_B;
        int[] sizeBnode = new int[MAX_CONS];
        int*[] startB = new int*[MAX_CONS];
        int[] nodeParent = new int[MAX_CONS];
        Int64[] Bparent = new Int64[MAX_COLS / 64 + 1];
        int[] sizeB = new int[MAX_CONS];
        int* bptr;
        int* A;
        int[] Real_A;
        int*[] startA = new int*[MAX_CONS];
        int[] sizeA = new int[MAX_CONS];
        int highc = 1;
        int startCol = 0;

        public unsafe void init()
        {
            Real_A = new int[MAX_FOR_A];
            Real_B = new int[MAX_FOR_B];

            fixed (int* tempPTR = Real_A) { A = tempPTR; };
            fixed (int* tempPTR = Real_B) { B = tempPTR; };
            bptr = B;
            cxtFileInput();
            for (int i = 0; i < MAX_COLS / 64 + 1; i++) Bparent[i] = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) A[i] = i;
            startA[0] = &A[0];
            startA[1] = &A[m];
            sizeB[0] = 0;
            startB[0] = &B[0];
            nodeParent[0] = -1;
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) colOriginal[i] = i;
            sortColumns();
            startCol = 0;
            while (colSup[startCol] == 0) startCol++;
            //sortRows();
            fixed (Int64* someP = Bparent)
            {
                InClose(0, startCol, someP);
            }
            Console.WriteLine(highc);
        }
        void InClose(int c, int y, Int64* Bparent)
        {
            int[] Bchildren = new int[MAX_COLS];
            int numchildren = 0;
            int[] Cnums = new int[MAX_COLS];
            Int64[] Bchild = new Int64[MAX_COLS / 64 + 1];

            // Needs Review
            for (int i = 0; i < nArray * 8; i++)
                Bchild[i] = Bparent[i];
            //Array.Copy(Bchild,Bparent,);


            if (c == 1)
            {
                Bchild[(y - 1) >> 6] = Bchild[(y - 1) >> 6] | (1L << ((y - 1) % 64));
                *bptr = y - 1;
                bptr++;
                sizeBnode[c]++;
            }
            long sizeAc = startA[c + 1] - startA[c];
            for (int j = y; j < n; j++)
            {
                if ((Bchild[j >> 6] & (1L << (j % 64))) == 0)
                {
                    int* Ac = startA[c];
                    int* aptr = startA[highc];
                    for (long i = sizeAc; i > 0; i--)
                    {
                        if ((context[*Ac][j >> 6] & (1L << (j % 64))) == 1)
                        {
                            *aptr = *Ac;
                            aptr++;
                        }
                        Ac++;
                    }
                    long size = aptr - startA[highc];
                    if (size == 0)
                    {
                        Bchild[j >> 6] = Bchild[j >> 6] | (1L << (j % 64));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (size < sizeAc)
                        {
                            if (IsCannonical(j, aptr, Bchild))
                            {
                                Bchildren[numchildren] = j;
                                Cnums[numchildren++] = highc;
                                nodeParent[highc] = c;
                                startA[++highc] = aptr;
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            *bptr = j;
                            bptr++;
                            Bchild[j >> 6] = Bchild[j >> 6] | (1L << (j % 64));
                            sizeBnode[c]++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            for (int i = numchildren - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                startB[Cnums[i]] = bptr;
                fixed (Int64* someP = Bchild)
                {
                    InClose(Cnums[i], Bchildren[i] + 1, someP);
                }
            }
        }
        bool IsCannonical(int y, int* endAhighc, Int64[] Bchild)
        {
            Int64[] Bmask = new Int64[MAX_COLS / 64 + 1];
            int p;
            for (p = 0; p < y >> 6; p++)
            {
                Bmask[p] = ~Bchild[p];
            }
            Bmask[p] = ~Bchild[p] & (1L << (y % 64)) - 1;

            for (p = 0; p <= y >> 6; p++)
            {
                long i;
                int* Ahighc = startA[highc];
                for (i = endAhighc - Ahighc; i > 0; i--)
                {
                    Bmask[p] = Bmask[p] & context[*Ahighc][p];
                    if (Bmask[p] > 0) break;
                    Ahighc++;
                }
                if (i == 0) return (false);
            }
            return (true);
        }

        void sortColumns()
        {
            int temp, i, j;
            for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                for (j = 0; j < n - i - 1; j++)
                {
                    if (colSup[j] > colSup[j + 1])
                    {
                        temp = colSup[j];
                        colSup[j] = colSup[j + 1];
                        colSup[j + 1] = temp;
                        temp = colOriginal[j];
                        colOriginal[j] = colOriginal[j + 1];    //keep track of original columns
                        colOriginal[j + 1] = temp;
                    }
                }
            }
            int[] tempColNums = new int[MAX_COLS];
            int[] rank = new int[MAX_COLS];
            for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
            {
                tempColNums[j] = colOriginal[j];
                rank[colOriginal[j]] = j;
            }
            for (j = 0; j < n - 1; j++)
            {
                for (i = 0; i < mArray; i++)
                {
                    Int64 temp64 = contextTemp[j][i];
                    contextTemp[j][i] = contextTemp[tempColNums[j]][i];
                    contextTemp[tempColNums[j]][i] = temp64;
                }
                tempColNums[rank[j]] = tempColNums[j];
                rank[tempColNums[j]] = rank[j];
            }
            for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
            {
                for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
                {
                    if ((contextTemp[j][(i >> 6)] & (1L << (i % 64))) == 1)
                        context[i][(j >> 6)] |= (1L << (j % 64));
                }
            }
            //delete [] contextTemp; 
        }
        void cxtFileInput()
        {
            int i, j;
            m = 8124;       //input number of objects
            n = 126;        //input number of attributes
            mArray = (m - 1) / 64 + 1;
            contextTemp = new Int64[n][];
            for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
            {
                contextTemp[j] = new Int64[mArray];
                for (i = 0; i < mArray; i++) contextTemp[j][i] = 0;
            }

            nArray = (n - 1) / 64 + 1;
            context = new Int64[m][];
            for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
            {
                context[i] = new Int64[nArray];
                for (j = 0; j < nArray; j++) context[i][j] = 0;
            }


            string instance;
            System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"C:\FCA\mushroom.txt");
            for (i = 0; i < m;i++ )
            {
                instance = file.ReadLine();
                for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
                    if (instance[j] == 'X')
                    {
                        contextTemp[j][(i >> 6)] |= (1L << (i % 64));
                        colSup[j]++;
                        Console.Write(contextTemp[j][(i >> 6)]+",");
                    }
                Console.WriteLine("-");
            }
            file.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Some explanations:

The main function in C++ calls `cxtFileInput()` which reads a matrix `W126 X H8124` stored as `X` (indicating 1) and `.` (indicating 0) then stores the input in arrays.

The main array is context which will be passed to `InClose` to generate FCA intents (FCA concept term) with checking the cannonacity of each generated intent. There are many functions in the original source code that I don't need now. The three functions listed above are the backbone of the algorithm.

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"C:\FCA\mushroom.txt");
> for (i = 0; i < m;i++ )
> {
>     // ...
> }
> file.Close();
> ```

Using `using` instead:

```
using (System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"C:\FCA\mushroom.txt"))
{
    for (i = 0; i < m;i++ )
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

This will ensure that `file` is disposed correctly.

---

> ```
> return (true);
> ```

Those parenthesis are useless and confusing.  Remove them.

---

> ```
> if (size == 0)
> {
>     // ...
> }
> else
> {
>     if (size < sizeAc)
>     {
>         // ...
>     }
>     else
>     {
>         // ...
>     }
> }
> ```

This can become:

```
if (size == 0)
{
    // ...
}
else if (size < sizeAc)
{
    // ...
}
else
{
    // ...
}
```

---

> ```
> int n;
> int m;
> int* B;
> ```

Those names don't tell me what the variable does or is used for.  Using a longer, more descriptive name won't affect performance, and will make debugging and maintaining the code easier.

Comment: It's valid C#, though it's in an `unsafe` context which is why it looks so odd: you can use **real** pointers in `unsafe` with C#.

Comment: @EBrown I understand.  However, I think this can be written without the unsafe context.

Comment: It can be, and the OP mentions that. But performance is an issue, which is why it's written as this.

Comment: Alright, I will remove that top comment.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have much this moment, but if you could provide a little bit more information as to how things are calculated and what some expected output is that will help.

I see that you are doing a C approach to this, and some of the C++ habbits are rubbing off in the C# code. Here are 2 things I spotted right off

C# initializes values to 0 by default making this code a waste of cycles

```
for (int i = 0; i < mArray; i++)
    contextTemp[j][i] = 0;
```

C# supports Jagged arrays and Multidimensional arrays. Which are you trying to use?

```
long[,] longArray2d = new long[2,10]; //2 rows, 10 columns
//jagged version of same thing
long[][] longArray2d = new long[2];
for(int i=0; i<longArray2d.Length; i++)
    longArray2d[i] = new long[10];
```

The last thing I want to mention is that if you pull this out into a unit test (which is very difficult, but I got it working) you'll be able to time it. I loaded up mushroom.txt to what I assume you have, but the output is a bit..well confusing (here are the first 6 lines of data that I got back of the 8124) so the question is.. how does one determine if this is right?

```
1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,-
2,3,3,2,3,2,3,3,2,3,3,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,2,2,2,-
6,4,7,4,7,4,7,7,6,4,7,6,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,6,6,4,-
9,11,8,12,15,9,15,15,9,12,15,9,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,9,9,9,-
22,27,23,16,16,31,16,22,19,16,25,31,31,31,31,31,31,31,16,22,16,18,-
54,59,40,34,47,34,63,47,54,44,47,38,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,47,41,38,50,-
```

Comment: Good thing to point out the `C approach to a C# environment` aspect.